# What is the difference between two intents: Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED, Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED?

Tags: android, android-intent

In which cases each of them should be used?
For example, to trigger some function inside the package upon this package update (installing over existing version of the package) which one should be used? Is it enough for that to use only one ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED?

Description from official documentation for [Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED):

> Added in API level 3
>
> public static final String ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED
>
> Broadcast Action: A new version of an application package has been
> installed, replacing an existing version that was previously
> installed. The data contains the name of the package.
>
> May include the following extras: EXTRA_UID containing the integer uid
> assigned to the new package.
>
> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"

Description for [Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED):

> Added in API level 12
>
> public static final String ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
>
> Broadcast Action: A new version of your application has been installed
> over an existing one. This is only sent to the application that was
> replaced. It does not contain any additional data; to receive it, just
> use an intent filter for this action.
>
> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is "broadcast" solely to the application that was just updated.

`ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`, in theory, is broadcast to any application on the device that is listening for such broadcasts. In practice, on Android 8.0 and higher, since that broadcast is not on [the allowlist](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/broadcasts/broadcast-exceptions), you may not be able to receive such broadcasts through a `<receiver>` manifest element.

> to trigger some function inside the package upon this package update (installing over existing version of the package) which one should be used? Is it enough for that to use only one ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED?

Yes.

Comment: If the application is listening both of this events (intents) the handling code will be executed twice upon receiving each of one? In this case will it be right to configure to listen to only one of them? Better to choose ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED or it does not matter?

Comment: @AntonSamokat: "Better to choose ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" -- yes.